# insert into tables from another tables

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins

Well, I trying insert into tables to another but I get this error;

WordPress database error: `[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''lcl_user_agent' (user_agent, hitcount, click_timestap) SELECT visite_useragent,' at line 1]`

This is my code;

```
$addagent = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->prefix.'lcl_user_agent' (user_agent, hitcount, click_timestap) SELECT visite_useragent, visite_hitcount, click_timestap FROM $wpdb->prefix.'lcl_visite_agent' .agent_id IN (' . $agent_id . ')";

$wpdb->query($addagent);
```

I want insert into lcl_user_agent the visites from visite_useragent then I get the visite for block with `$agent_id` from the form

Comment: Might be the single quotes for a table name: `'lcl_user_agent'`, either remove or use double quotes (Standard SQL) or backticks (MySQL).

Comment: @dnoeth I dont know how to do that, I put "lcl_user_agent" and it give me a error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're messing up at the very end.
It should be this form:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

So maybe this is what you're going for?

```
$addagent = '
 INSERT INTO 
        '.$wpdb->prefix.'lcl_user_agent
        (user_agent, hitcount, click_timestap) 
    SELECT 
        visite_useragent, visite_hitcount, click_timestap 
    FROM 
        '.$wpdb->prefix.'lcl_visite_agent
    WHERE
        agent_id IN (' . $agent_id . ')
 ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

`$addagent = "INSERT INTO " . $wpdb->prefix . 'lcl_user_agent' . " (user_agent, hitcount, click_timestap) SELECT visite_useragent, visite_hitcount, click_timestap FROM " . $wpdb->prefix.'lcl_visite_agent' . " where agent_id IN (' . $agent_id . ')";`

`$wpdb->query($addagent);`

I've never had much luck embedding the -> within a double-quoted string. Just makes it more clear to concatenate the strings together. Also, in this case, unless you have multiple `$agent_id` values, you might consider `where agent_id = $agent_id` instead  of using IN.

Comment: It not work for me with this I dont have a error but it doesn't insert any value into lcl_user_agent, but thank you so much for your time! take care